# Selenium ChromeDriver not found at TeamCity

Tags: .net, visual-studio, selenium, teamcity

I'm having this problem:

> The chromedriver.exe file does not exist in the current directory or
>   in a directory on the PATH environment variable.

This problem occurs **ONLY** at TeamCity, which is in the same machine that I'm working. If I run the test on my machine using Visual Studio, it works.

I noticed that TeamCity is working at an "out" folder. Ex:

```
C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\SYSTEM_MACHINE_NAME 2015-12-03 13_51_08\Out
```

But this "out" folder doesn't have the ChromeDriver. It is on 2 folders above.

The ChromeDrive is set to "Content/Copy Always". I also tried "Copy if Newer". They aren't copied at "out" folder of TeamCity build.

What am I missing?

```
private IWebDriver _driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: Are you using nuget to retrieve Chrome webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding a [DeploymentItem] on TestClass:

```
[TestClass]
[DeploymentItem("chromedriver.exe")]
[DeploymentItem("IEDriverServer.exe")]
[DeploymentItem("phantomjs.exe")]
public class BaseTest
{
   ...
}
```